# Swift method to iterating through array to populate tableviewcells

Tags: json, swift

I'm trying to use http POST to get a JSON array to populate my tableviewcontroller. This is the code I have now:

```
let myJSON = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: data!, options: []) as! NSArray
    print (myJSON)
    let testArr = myJSON[0] as! [String:Any]
    print (testArr)
    let testVar = testArr["Username"] as! String
    print (testVar)

    for object in myJSON {
        //error line below
        guard let cellItem = History1(name: object.Username, status: "Placeholder") else {
            fatalError("cannot create")
        }
        self.history1s += [cellItem]
    }
```

myJSON is json response from mysql statement "SELECT * FROM USER". Right now I'm having the error "Value of type 'Any' has no member 'Username'. Wrapping Username in square brackets gives me the error "User of unresolved identifier Username"

I don't really understand why the prints work but the below loop doesn't.

I think there's something fundamentally wrong with how I'm approaching this method. I'm very new at Swift so a lot of terms might not make sense to me. Any advice will be appreciated.

Comment: Please fix the code you posted. You certainly don't want the 2nd line you posted.

Comment: Hint: `object` in your `for` loop is equivalent to your `testArr` variable.

Comment: @rmaddy I tried using "object["Lock_ID"] as! String" but now I have an error  Type NSFastEnumerationIteratorElement has no subscript members...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try to loop by keys and then get object by key

```
for key in myJSON.keys {
//error line below
guard let cellItem = History1(name: myJSON[key].Username, status: "Placeholder") else {
fatalError("cannot create")
}
self.history1s += [cellItem]
}
```